# predicateWithFormat:argumentArray: Using Only First item in NSArray

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm writing a fetchedResultsController for my core data model, and am having an issue with the predicate only using 1 item out of the argumentArray. If the array has 3 items, it will print out this: `NOT unique == "16C0629D-F8B6-4DF3-9AAD-820821B6D325"` and only search against the first item.

My complete fetchedResultsController code is below. I've searched a bunch and can't seem to find much discussion on the method that I'm using. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
  NSMutableArray *opponentUniques = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (Opponent *opponent in self.opponentArray) {
    [opponentUniques addObject:opponent.personUnique];
  }
  NSPredicate *searchPredicate = nil;
  if ([opponentUniques count] > 0) {
      searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!(unique == %@)" argumentArray:opponentUniques];
  }

  NSFetchRequest *allPeople = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
  allPeople.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];
  allPeople.predicate = searchPredicate;
  self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:allPeople
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this will work:  `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (self.unique IN %@)", opponentUniques]`

Comment: That was the answer! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `NSPredicate` correctly. Take a look at `NSCompundPredicate`. You want something like [`andPredicateWithArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCompoundPredicate/andPredicateWithSubpredicates).